# Understanding why the tangent bundle of a unit circle is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times\mathbb R$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle#cite_note-disjoint-1)  defines a tangent bundle of a manifold $M$ as
$$\coprod_{x\in M}T_{x}M = \{(x,y)| x\in M, y\in T_x M\} .$$

The wiki link describes the tangent bundle of $S_1$ as being diffeomorphic to $S_1\times R$ by saying the way to make the tangent spaces at all points of the circle (which are in the plane of the circle) disjoint smoothly is by aligning them perpendicular to the plane of the circle which I don't understand completely.

The tangent space at a point on the circle, is just the tangent line at that point and the line is not tangent to any other point on the circle, so aren't the tangent spaces disjoint to begin with? Thanks and appreciate a hint.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The tangent space to a manifold $M$ is a disjoint union like you say: More precisely, if a vector $X \in TM$ is in the tangent space $T_p M$ to $p$, it's not in $T_q M$ for any $q \neq p$.

Now, if a manifold $M$ is viewed as a submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$, it is sometimes useful to identify the tangent space $T_p M$ as an affine subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ tangent to $M$ at $p$. For example, we might identify the tangent space $T_z S^1$ at $z \in S^1 \subset \Bbb R^2$ with $\{w : z \cdot (w - z) = 0\}$. This identification, however, can lead to confusion, and this confusion is exactly what the comment in the Wikipedia article aims to prevent: For $z' \in S^1$, $z' \neq \pm z$, the affine spaces in $\Bbb R^2$ we identify with $T_z S^1$ and $T_{z'} S^1$ intersect, even though $T_z S^1$ and $T_{z'} S^1$ are themselves disjoint.

If we view $\Bbb R^2$ as a plane in $\Bbb R^3$, one can imagine rotating each such affine line in $\Bbb R^2$ a quarter turn to be orthogonal to the plane of the circle; then, these lines are pairwise disjoint (hence resolving the above issue) and comprise a cylinder ($S^1 \times \Bbb R$) that we can identify with the tangent space $T S^1$. (This is perhaps misleading in its own way, but if it helps you, great.)

We can make the identification $TS^1 \leftrightarrow S^1 \times \Bbb R$ in another way, by the way: If we identify $\Bbb R^2 \cong \Bbb C$, then as above we have a canonical identifiaction $T_1 \Bbb C \cong \Bbb C$. Then identifying $$S^1 = \{z \in \Bbb C : |z| = 1\}$$ identifies $T_1 S^1$ with the imaginary axis $i \Bbb R \subset \Bbb C$. By symmetry, for any $z \in S^1$, the rotation of $S^1$ that takes $z$ to $1$ (namely, multiplication by $z^{-1} = \bar z$) maps $T_{z'} S^1$, again viewed as an affine space in $\Bbb C$ to $T_1 S^1$. This in fact defines a diffeomorphism $TS^1 \cong S^1 \times i \Bbb R$ by
$(z, X) \mapsto (z, z^{-1} X)$, where we regard $X$ as an element of $T_z \Bbb C \cong \Bbb C$. Of course, $i \Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R$ are canonically isomorphic given by the map that divides by $i$, defining an isomorphism
$$TS^1 \cong S^1 \times \Bbb R, \qquad (z, X) \mapsto (z, -i z^{-1} X) .$$

*Remark* Here we took advantage of the fact that $S^1$ can be viewed as a Lie group and let it act on itself on the left. Essentially the same construction gives for any Lie group $G$ an explicit diffeomorphism $TG \cong G \times \operatorname{Lie}(G)$, which in particular shows that every Lie group is parallelizable.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation! In the 4th paragraph, it should be $T_z S^{1}$ instead of $T_p S^{1}$, being nit picky here.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you found it useful. And thanks for the correction, I just fixed the issue!

Comment: I sure did, especially about the generalization to Lie groups. Just checking if the following would also be a diffeomorphism: $TS^{1} = \{(x,v)\in S^{'}\times R^2|<x,v>=0\}$, $\implies x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1, x_1 v_1+x_2 v_2=0 \implies$  $v$ is a multiple of $(x_2,-x_1)$. To find the length of $(v_1,v_2)$, we can take inner product of $(v_1,v_2)$ with $(-x_2,x_1)$ as $(-x_2,x_1)$ has unit length. Let $t = x_2 v_1 - x_1 v_2$ and the diffeomorphism $TS^{1}:\rightarrow S^{1}\times R$ being $(x,v)\rightarrow (x,x_2 v_1-x_1 v_2)$? Appreciate your time.

Comment: Yes, and this is a very nice way to write this map, too. (I would describe the inner product as the *signed length* of $(v_1, v_2)$, but this is exactly what you want anyway.) Note that the component $v_1 x_2 - x_1 v_2$ is just $\det\pmatrix{v&x}$, or just as well, the nonzero component of the cross product $v \times x$, regarding $v, x$ as elements of $\Bbb R^3$ via the identification $u \leftrightarrow (u, 0)$, or, again just as well, $\Omega(v, x)$, where $\Omega = dx_1 \wedge dx_2$ is the standard volume form on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not think of it as det $(v x)$, good point :)

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I don't understand this: $T_1S^1 \subset T_1\Bbb{R}^2 \cong \Bbb{R}^2 \cong \Bbb{C}$. The tangent space of 1 in $S_1$ is a subset of $T_1\Bbb{R}^2$? What is this latter thing? The tangent at 1 (of $S_1$) considered as an element of $R^2$? (If it's not obvious, I'm a novice here).

Comment: Just as $T_1 S^1$ is the tangent space to $S^1$ at the point $1 \in S^1$, the symbol $T_1 \Bbb R^2$ denotes to the tangent space to $\Bbb R^2$ at the point $1$. Under most circumstances we'd denote this point $(1, 0)$ when viewing it as a point in $\Bbb R^2$, but this notation emphasizes that, when we view $S^1$ as the unit circle in $\Bbb R^2$, the points $1 \in S^1$ and $(1, 0) \in \Bbb R^2$ coincide, but perhaps this notation is unappealing or confusing, instead identify $\Bbb R^2$ with $\Bbb C$ in the usual way, and then consider $T_1 S^1 \subset T_1 \Bbb C$.

Comment: More generally, if $N$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$, then for any point $p \in N$ we can identify $T_p N$ as the subspace of $T_p M$ consisting exactly of the vectors that in $T_p M$ that are tangent to $N$.